# Counting lines in polygons in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, st-intersects

I have a grid polygon layer and a line layer.

Once imported into PostGIS (let's call the tables `poly` and `line`), how can one build a query (with `ST_Intersect` for example) that counts the number of line intersections with polygons (the same as the QGIS tool:  `MMQGIS > Spatial Join > Intersects > First`)

and returns the `poly` table with an extra column containing the sum of line intersections per polygon?

In some cases, the same line will intersect the same polygon more than once, and in that case, it should only be counted once.

So far, I have this:

```
 CREATE TABLE sp_join AS
 SELECT polygons.* COUNT (l.*)
 FROM  polygons as p
 JOIN lines l ON  ST_Intersects(p.wkb_geometry, lines.wkb_geometry)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a new table with all the columns **and rows** with an added count of overlapping figures, you need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to populate rows where no data exists:

```
CREATE TABLE sp_join AS
    SELECT polygons.*, count(l.idcol) as line_count
    FROM  polygons p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lines l ON
        ST_Intersects(p.wkb_geometry, l.wkb_geometry)
    GROUP BY p.idcol
```

This assumes a primary key column named `idcol` exists in each table.

The default behavior is to only return a row once where there are multiple intersections, so nothing special is required in this regard.

Note that it's confusing to name a column of "geometry" type "wkb_geometry", because it's not storing the data in WKB format -- "geom" or "point"/"line"/"poly" better describe the column.  Best practice would be to explicitly list each column in the `SELECT` list, but you didn't provide the column names.

Comment: Without a GROUP BY clause it doesn't work. Add a GROUP BY with the primary key of polygon table.

Comment: yeah, my bad (reinstalling PG at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both tables have a primary key called gid.

I can not test it right now but something like this could work:

```
SELECT poly.gid, count(*) 
FROM poly, lines
WHERE ST_Intersects(p.wkb_geometry, lines.wkb_geometry)
GROUP BY poly.gid
```